# `require('dotenv').config()` does not work when webpack builds

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, dotenv

I'm trying to selectively set my environment variables using `dotenv` module and `NODE_ENV` value.

I use this `env.js` file to set up my custom environment variables:

```js
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV
require('dotenv').config()

switch (NODE_ENV) {
  case 'development':
    process.env.REACT_API_URL = process.env.DEV_API_URL
    process.env.REACT_BUILD_PATH = process.env.DEV_BUILD_PATH
    process.env.REACT_BUILD_MODE = 'development'
    break
  case 'production':
    process.env.REACT_API_URL = process.env.PROD_API_URL
    process.env.REACT_BUILD_PATH = process.env.PROD_BUILD_PATH
    process.env.REACT_BUILD_MODE = 'production'
    break
  default:
    throw new Error('NODE_ENV is not a valid value: should be \'development\' or \'production\' ')
    break
}

const REACT = /^REACT_/i
const raw = Object.keys(process.env)
  .filter(key => REACT.test(key))
  .reduce(
    (env, key) => {
      env[key] = process.env[key]
      return env
    },
    {

    }
  )
const stringified = {
  'process.env': Object.keys(raw).reduce((env, key) => {
    env[key] = JSON.stringify(raw[key])
    return env
  }, {})
}

module.exports = { raw, stringified }
```

I copied and modified some of them from `CRA`'s scripts. So using this code, with `.env` file provided, if I run node REPL like `NODE_ENV=development node` and run `require('./env')` with this file, I can get a result like this:

```
// .env
DEV_API_URL=http://localhost:4000
DEV_BUILD_PATH=../../ssr/build
```

```js
{ raw:
   { REACT_API_URL: 'http://localhost:4000',
     REACT_BUILD_PATH: '../../ssr/build',
     REACT_BUILD_MODE: 'development' },
  stringified:
   { 'process.env':
      { REACT_API_URL: '"http://localhost:4000"',
        REACT_BUILD_PATH: '"../../ssr/build"',
        REACT_BUILD_MODE: '"development"' } } }
```

With this, I expected to see the same result from `env.js` so that I can use it when I build my React bundle with Webpack. But the result was not like what I thought. The `webpack.config.js` file (essential version) looks like below:

```js
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

const env = require('./env')

module.exports = {
  entry: ["core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime", "./src/index.jsx"],
  output: {

  // ...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified)
  ]
}
```

In the above code, I imported `env.js` object to use it as custom `process.env`. But inside the `process.env`, things were not like what I wanted:

```js
// if I do `console.log(env)`:
{ raw:
   { REACT_API_URL: 'undefined',
     REACT_BUILD_PATH: 'undefined',
     REACT_BUILD_MODE: 'development' },
  stringified:
   { 'process.env':
      { REACT_API_URL: '"undefined"',
        REACT_BUILD_PATH: '"undefined"',
        REACT_BUILD_MODE: '"development"' } } }
```

The thing is that `require('dotenv').config()` in `env.js` was not being invoked at all, so any variables using `process.env` to initialize did not have any value in them. Is this proper action? What should I do if I want to achieve what I wanted to do?